# Why isn't there a native string method to change a string title case?

Tags: c#, string, function

Something that's been bugging me while working on a recent project; why doesn't C# have a native function to change a string to title case?

e.g.

```
string x = "hello world! THiS IS a Test mESSAGE";
string y = x.ToTitle(); // y now has value of "Hello World! This Is A Test Message"
```

We have `.ToLower` and `.ToUpper`, and I appreciate you can use `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase` or create a TextInfo object (the same process), but it's just so... ugly.

Anyone know the reason?

Comment: It's part of CultureInfo because it varies by culture.

Comment: But ToUpper/ToLower also varies by culture (or should do).

Comment: You could make this exact extension to the string class and use it all you want. Why din't you?

Comment: @loxdog Note that even `TextInfo.ToTitleCase` won't get your case right - as `IS` is all capitals, it sees it as an acronym and leaves it in upper case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it has: [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx)

Why it is there? Because casing depends on current culture. E.g. Turkish cultures have different uppercase and lowercase for 'i' and 'I' characters. Read more about this [here](http://www.siao2.com/2004/12/03/274288.aspx).

UPDATE: Actually I agree with @Cashley which says that missing `ToTitleCase` method on `String` class looks like an oversight of MicroSoft. If you will look on `String.ToUpper()` or `String.ToLower()` you will see that both use `TextInfo` internally:

```
public string ToUpper()
{
    return this.ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}

public string ToUpper(CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (culture == null)    
        throw new ArgumentNullException("culture");

    return culture.TextInfo.ToUpper(this);
}
```

So, I think there should be same method for `ToTitleCase()`. Maybe .NET team decided to add to `String` class only those methods, which are mostly used. I don't see any other reason for keeping `ToTitleCase` away.

Comment: So why aren't ToUpper and ToLower relegated to `TextInfo`, as they have the same cultural issue?

Comment: Looks like [String uses CultureInfo internally](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/String@cs/1305376/String@cs) - I guess just an oversight on the the part of MS not adding ToTitleCase to String as well.

Comment: That explains it! I'll write it off as a Microsoft oversight, but it'd be nice if they resolved it...

Comment: @loxdog frankly speaking, I use `ToLower` or `ToUpper` quite often, but I used `ToTitleCase` one or two times in my life, so seems frequency of usage is a good reason to keep this method out of String class. So, maybe its by design. I think only guys from MS can say for sure

Comment: This is true; I'd typically do it from the data source or force it when the data is supplied anyway. Just an unusual circumstance I'm using it for I suppose!

Answer (score 0):

[There's an extension method](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0140__Class/Addtitlecasetostringclass.htm) for this here, but it's not culture specific.

Possibly better implementation just wrapping CurrentCulture.TextInfo like String.ToUpper:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "test Title cAsE";
        s = s.ToTitleCase();
        Console.Write(s);
    }
}
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string inputString)
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(inputString);
    }

    public static string ToTitleCase(this string inputString, CultureInfo ci)
    {
        return ci.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(inputString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim myString As String = "wAr aNd pEaCe"

  ' Creates a TextInfo based on the "en-US" culture.
  Dim myTI As TextInfo = New CultureInfo("en-US", False).TextInfo

  ' Changes a string to titlecase.
  Console.WriteLine("""{0}"" to titlecase: {1}", myString, myTI.ToTitleCase(myString))
```

OR

```
  string myString = "wAr aNd pEaCe";

  // Creates a TextInfo based on the "en-US" culture.
  TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

  // Changes a string to titlecase.
  Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" to titlecase: {1}", myString, myTI.ToTitleCase(myString));
```